# Фон на 2 половины boostrap 4

Tags: bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

Как правильно сверстать данный блок? делаю с boostrap 4 (он идет в 100% ширину)
 2 блока по 50% фоном и что бы контент остался в контейнере по колонкам
[image: как сдесь]

Comment: @MaximLensky, а bootstrap - это не обычный css? :))

Answer (score 0):

Вот если что решение, может кому то пригодится

```css
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 69, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 69, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.bg .container {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">Left</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">Right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: а в чём его адаптивность ? если эта штука так же сжимается как и обычный блок при 50% width -- ммм?

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}

.section-inner {
  padding: 3rem 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

.col-left:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: blue;
  left: -888px;
}

.col-left {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-left">
        <div class="section-inner">
          <h2>About Us</h2>

          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci non provident ullam! Numquam nemo modi dolorum et ea, quae nulla?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-right">
        <div class="section-inner">
          <h2>About Us</h2>

          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Adipisci non provident ullam! Numquam nemo modi dolorum et ea, quae nulla?
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```